# How to permanently limit cpu frequency

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to limit the cpu frequency of my Linux machine.
I know about cpufreq sysfs, but limiting online is too late in my case.

Is there a kernel parameter for this?

Where do the values for `cpuinfo_max_freq` and `scaling_max_freq` come from?
Can I change them before the governor starts changing cpu frequencies?
Can I change the default governor (to powersave for example)?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by compiling the kernel and enabling only the "powersave" governor.

> This sets the frequency statically to the lowest frequency supported
>   by the CPU

Check [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/) to see if this can be set as kernel parameter for a multi-governor kernel